# C - Singly linked list - passing a pointer by value vs by reference

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
typedef struct node { int data; struct node *next; } NODE;

NODE* add_head(NODE **phead, int data) {
  NODE *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
  new->data = data;
  new->next = *phead;
  *phead = new;
  return new;
}

NODE* add_tail(NODE **phead, int data) {
  NODE *p, *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
  new->data = data;
  new->next = 0;
  if (*phead == 0) *phead = new;
  else
  {
    for (p = *phead; p->next; p = p->next);
    p->next = new;
  }
  return new;
}
```

We have a singly linked list as shown above in the functions. The node consists of the data type int and the pointer to the next node in the list. We have two functions defined. The first one changes the head node, or adds the new head node before the previous head node. The second function adds the tail node (the last one in the list). In the main, we call them like:

```
NODE *head = 0;
NODE *c1 = add_head(&head, 1);
NODE *c2 = add_tail(&head, 3);
```

Now, look at this function:

```
NODE* add_after(NODE *node, int data) {
  NODE *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
  new->data = data;

  new->next = node->next;
  node->next = new;

  return new;
}
```

That function adds a node after the argument node. And, in main, if we want to add a node after c1 previously defined, we call the function like:

```
*c3 = add_after(c1, 4);
```

My question is: What is the difference between first two and the third function in terms of the arguments. In first two functions, we have an argument **phead and in the third function, *node. Do we really need **phead, why can't we just put *phead and in the main call it like:

```
NODE *c1 = add_head(head, 1);
```

I hope you understood what I meant, I find it difficult to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The address of the first element (of type `NODE`) is contained in a pointer (of type `NODE *`)
- the `add_head()` functions modifies this pointer. As you are programming in C, blatantly lacking parameter-passing-by-reference, your only option is to transmit its address.

So, the parameter is of type `NODE**` (adress of a pointer to a NODE).

- for `add_after()` the parameter gives the address of the NODE to be modified. You don't have to modify that address.

Comment: `NODE* add_head(NODE *phead, int data) {`
  `NODE *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));`
  `new->data = data;`
  `new->next = phead;`
  `phead = new;`
  `return new;`
`}`
What would happen if we had that function?

Comment: @A6SE well, you'll see by yourself if you try to build a list using your add_head function, and then print its first element. Better try than speculate (or believing without seeing).

Comment: Image in the edit section kind of made me understand :D
edit: cannot post images, but here's the link: https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t35.0-12/899637_10205653784815332_1271825706_o.jpg?oh=15e3ffd465e8c832690f0b6cae1a63dc&oe=556D874C